# Phonegap: Can iPhone web app access/check for wifi connections

Tags: iphone, cordova, wifi, web-applications

I have tried looking for some answers but could not get anything concrete from the other questions in here.

I am looking for an answer to these two questions:

1. Using PhoneGap, if I create an iPhone web app, can I use it as
   plain web app (i.e. without using iTunes to deploy it)? Just via a
   web url?
2. Using PhoneGap, can an iPhone web app check for wifi
   connectivity? i.e. If wifi/3g is available, if wifi is available,
   can it scan for ssids.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create host the web app on your own server (or local). Then it is accessible via web url. If you want to use it as a normal app (there are differences - phonegap uses few native plugins for better experience), then you must have a developer license from apple and then deploy it to your device. Otherwise you can only use the simulator. You can also use Safari + USB to debug your app using the browser.
2. It is possible but limited. Only certain functionalities are available. Check out the following plugin for cordova (phonegap):
   [cordova-plugin-wifi](http://github.com/guyromb/cordova-plugin-wifi)

Good luck!